# Bootstrap row/columns are not collapsed by default?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have googled around and tried a few different things in terms of where to add the "collapse" class in my various div's, but I haven't found anything specific to collapsing rows.

I have a some code that looks like this:

```
<div id="test" class="collapse">
<div class="row" style="display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="col-md-10">
     Text
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

With (what I think) is the appropriate data-* attributes for collapsing:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-dropdown" data-target="#test" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

However, whenever I click, it takes about 2 tries for the "collapse" to actually exist (meaning I can collapse in/out), and more importantly, it does not display as collapsed by default. Is there something I am missing with using a flex container, or maybe with how I am using the collapse stuff from bootstrap?

I have tried moving around the collapse to different elements to no avail. Am I missing anything?

I can post more complete code if necessary, I just have the skeleton for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, so there something else in your code that's causing it not to be collapsed by default.

https://www.codeply.com/go/F7glxbJxGA

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-dropdown" data-target="#test" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
<div id="test" class="collapse">
    <div class="row" style="display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/sw2bnzeq/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-default btn-dropdown" data-target="#test" data-toggle="collapse">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
<div id="test" class="collapse">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess you might have missed the **jQuery** or **bootstrap.min.js**

Comment: Well, the thing is, the collapse works after clicking on the button a few times. It's not that it doesn't work at all, simply that the initial state is that it is not collapsed, when it should be collapsed.

Comment: @imdumb ...  I didn't get your point... Could you please elaborate on the issue.... **the initial state is that it is not collapsed, when it should be collapsed** What do you mean by this???

Comment: @imdumb ..  Are you looking for this https://jsfiddle.net/sw2bnzeq/1/ ???